# Cannot install strace on Parrot Linux

Tags: linux, package, strace, parrot-os

I use Parrot OS. As I found out, strace is a basic package which i can install just by `apt-get install strace`. But i just get

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package strace is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
E: Package 'strace' has no installation candidate
```

Why so? M/b somebody nows

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [parrot repo](http://deb.parrotsec.org/parrot/pool/main/s/), the `strace` package is present.

This means that either your apt database is outdated, in this case, you can update it using `apt update`, or apt is not using this repo.

If so, you can add the Parrot Repo by creating/updating your `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/parrot.list` file with the content provided in the [documentation of Parrot](https://docs.parrotsec.org/doku.php/mirrors-list). Then you can update the list of packages and retry the installation!